# Svelte binded select value is not updating on fetch

Tags: javascript, html, binding, svelte

I'm using the following code in Svelte (3) to fetch options from an API. There's subsequent s that depend on the first one. My expectation is that selectedOption would change to options[0] when the select has its options populated but it's not changing until I manually select another option and then select the first one. Am I binding it wrong? AFAIK I don't need a reactive variable for this and should theoretically work like this.

```
onmount(async () => {
    options = await getOptions()
})
let selectedOption;

<select bind:value={selectedOption}>
{#each options as option}
    <option value={option} selected={selectedOption === option}>
        {option.name}
    </option>
{/each}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `bind:value` on a select only updates the bound variable when a change event fires. Since populating the options does not fire a change event, `selectedOption` won't be updated until you select an option.

I would suggest not rendering the `<select>` until options are completely populated. This will make sure `selectedOption` is set immediately.

```html
{#if options.length > 0}
    <select bind:value={selectedOption} >
        {#each options as option}
                <option value={option} selected={selectedOption === option}>
                        {option.name}
                </option>
        {/each}
    </select>
{/if}
```

Comment: Sorry, I shoud've added this on my question but I do have a conditional in the template, but it may be wrong since I'm doing {#if options} rather than {#if options.length > 0} which might be making things wonky.

Comment: What is `options` initialized to? If it's null or undefined, then `{#if options}` will be false. If it's an empty array then `{#if options}` will be true and the `<select>` will be rendered before the options are completely populated.

Answer (score 1):

you could also try svelte's {#await ... } block like this

```
<script lang="ts">
  interface IOption {
    id: number;
    name: string;
  }
  let selected: IOption;
  const getOptions = async () =>
    new Promise<IOption[]>((resolve) =>
      resolve([
        { id: 1, name: "foo" },
        { id: 2, name: "bar" },
      ])
    );

  $: console.log(selected);
</script>

<select bind:value={selected}>
  {#await getOptions() then options}
    {#each options as option}
      <option value={option} selected={option.id == selected.id}>
        {option.name}
      </option>
    {/each}
  {/await}
</select>
```

i took the liberty of defining the getOptions method so its easier to test

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you instantiate `selectedOption` after `getOptions()` function is finished executing. And you should also make `selected` be the 0 index option.

```js
let selectedOption;

onmount(async () => {
    options = await getOptions()
    selectedOption = options[0]
})

<select bind:value={selectedOption}>
{#each options as option}
    <option value={option} selected={option.id == 0}>
        {option.name}
    </option>
{/each}
```